# List of common environment variables for cross-platform, Apache Ant, builds

Tags: windows, macos, ant, build, environment-variables

Does anyone have a list of environment variables that are common on Linux, Windows, and OSX that would enable cross-platform, consistent Apache Ant builds?

For example:  On OSX you can specify env.HOME and perform file operations from the user's home directory, /Users/michaelprescott.  On Windows, env.HOME isn't available.  Instead, you have to specify env.HOMEDRIVE or env.HOMEPATH .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A lot of that is built into Java.  Definitely check out user.dir and similar from System.getProperties() which Ant will use.

Here's a list of some of the more interesting ones:

- file.encoding =  MacRoman
- file.separator =  /
- java.class.path =  ./
- java.class.version =  50.0
- java.endorsed.dirs =  /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.fram...
- java.ext.dirs =  /Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Ja...
- java.home =  /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Ver...
- java.io.tmpdir =  /var/folders/Kp/KpmOujsB2RWdqE+BYnAOX++++T...
- java.library.path =  .:/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Libr...
- java.specification.version =  1.6
- java.vendor =  Apple Inc.
- java.version =  1.6.0_20
- line.separator =
- os.arch =  x86_64
- os.name =  Mac OS X
- os.version =  10.6.3
- path.separator =  :
- user.country =  US
- user.dir =  /private/tmp/properties-test
- user.home =  /Users/dblevins
- user.language =  en
- user.name =  dblevins
- user.timezone =

Comment: Thanks!  Those are good enough for me and consistent across the platforms I tested.  It is curious that the Apache Ant documented method of using environment properties is inconsistent, whilst these are consistent.  This is the first time I've seen that java makes them available.  So, I could write a little java app that prints the results of System.getProperties() and see all the properties made available through file., java., path., and user.?

Answer (score 0):

You can always run:

```
$ ant -diagnostics
```

It will spew a lot of information, that you are looking for, to your console.